# Swift 2 - Bring selected CollectionView Cell in front of other cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift2

I have a `UICollectionView` in my view controller. It has been setup and its working fine.

I am trying to zoom a cell when a button inside the cell itself has been pressed.

The code I have zooms the cell however, I cannot find the way to force the cell selected to go to the front of the other cells.
Right now the cell selected its always behind the cell before the selected.

How can I force the cell selected to zoom in front of the other cells?

```
@IBAction func detailBtnAction(sender:UIButton){

        let indexUser = (sender.layer.valueForKey("indexBtn")) as! Int
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: indexUser, inSection: 0)
        let feedCell = feedCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            feedCell?.bringSubviewToFront(feedCollectionView)

        feedCell?.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(feedCollectionView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { () -> Void in
            feedCell?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5, 5)
        }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me what you are doing is a bad idea. In general Apple's complex UI objects (collection views, table views, pickers, etc) should be treated as "black boxes" and you should not mess with their view hierarchies. In the case of collection views, you own the content of each cell, but manipulating the size/order/transform of the cells themselves is likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have the order of things mixed up a little.

From the docs :

> Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.
>
> func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView)
>
> Parameters
>
> view - The subview to move to the front.
>
> This method moves the specified view to the end of the array of views in the subviews property.

So your call :
`feedCell?.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(feedCollectionView)`
actually means that the cells contentview should move the `feedCollectionView` to front.
Now, this is some educated guess based on the naming, but it should rather look like that :
`feedCollectionView.bringSubviewToFront(feedCell?)`

You can pass the cell itself there, as it inherits from `UIView`.

Comment: thank you so much.. Not sure why I was doing the opposite!!

Comment: No problem, sometimes the obvious things are the hardest to spot ;]

Answer (score 1):

To bring cell to the front. You can remove cell then after add again: `

`mCollectionView.reloadData()
mCollectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
            (result) in
            var indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            var cell = mCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
            cell.removeFromSuperview()
            mCollectionView.addSubview(cell)})`